# How to use System.Windows.Interactivity windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, eventtrigger

I've created a wpf C# project for windows phone 8.1 following MVVM Pattern.

I want to install the System.Windows.Interactivity dll so i can use the event trigger and EventToCommand and so on.

The problem is that once i reference the dll in my project, i got an error saying:

```
Unable to find the type System.Windows.DependencyObjectCollection`1 in system.windows.dll module
```

I got the DLL from :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries
```

I believe there is an incompatibility but when i look on internet i can see that some people use that library so i probably do something wrong when i add it..

I don't really understand.

Thank you for reading and helping,

Guillaume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compatible v8.1 `System.Windows.Interactivity` was distributed with the Windows Phone SDK.  If I recall correctly, it should show up when adding references by going to Assemblies > Extensions, but if not look in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDK*
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, it does the job for me.